# add element from dict to other dict with key condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to add element from dict to other dict with that the Key has the same value
for example, i have

```
A = [{ 'A' : 3 , 'B_id' : 1009 }, { 'A' : 3 , 'B_id' : 1010 }] 
B = [{ 'B_id' : 1009 , 'C' : 9 } , { 'B_id' : 1010 , 'C' : 10 }, { 'B_id' : 1011 , 'C' : 11 }]
```

i want to add 'C' from B to A only if 'B_id' of B is equal to 'B_id' of A
so A should be

```
A =  [{ 'A' : 3 , 'B_id' : 1009, 'C' : 9}, { 'A' : 3 , 'B_id' : 1010, 'C' : 10 }]
```

i tried looping the key of A,B and it is very slow... any way that make it faster?
This is the code:

```
for row in A:
 for rows in B:
   if(row['B_id'] == rows['B_id']):
      row['C'] = rows['C']
```

Comment: Sorry edited @ggorlen thanks for spotting this up !

Comment: Yes; use vectorized operations and a filter / `where` clause.
See your friendly neighborhood PANDAS tutorials for those concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `B_id` values are unique, you could create a lookup dictionary:

```
A = [{'A': 3, 'B_id': 1009}, {'A': 3, 'B_id': 1010}]
B = [{'B_id': 1009, 'C': 9}, {'B_id': 1010, 'C': 10}, {'B_id': 1011, 'C': 11}]

lookup = {d['B_id'] : d['C'] for d in B}

for a in A:
    if a['B_id'] in lookup:
        a['C'] = lookup[a['B_id']]

print(A)
```

**Output**

```
[{'A': 3, 'B_id': 1009, 'C': 9}, {'A': 3, 'B_id': 1010, 'C': 10}]
```

The (expected) time complexity of this approach is *O(N)*.

Comment: Wow thanks ! what if i have another key, let's say c_id on A,B and want to add only when both B_id and C_id are match @Dani Mesejo

Comment: @Wizarduy you could use a tuple as key, the tuple would composed by the values C_id and B_id

Comment: lookup = {d['B_id'] : d['C'] for d in B}
lookup2 = {d['C_id'] : d['C'] for d in B}
for a in A:
    if (a['B_id'] in lookup and a['C_id'] in lookup2):
        a['C'] = lookup[a['B_id']] i'm using like this now Thank you ! it's working

Comment: if i want to add B contains another key, let's say D and i want to add both 'C' and 'D' how should i create lookup in this case

Comment: You can also create a tuple as a value

Comment: lookup = { tuple( d['B_id'], d['C_id']) : tuple( d['C'], d['D] ) for d in B} this doesn't work...

Comment: oh shouldn't write tuple there. Thank you!